# Product grid homepage display category link

Tags: product, product-list, grid-layout

On our homepage we display a product grid with 6 products.
We want to display below every product a link to the category of that product.

So for example one of the products is a laptop.
Below that laptop I want to display a link with "See all laptops".

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could retrieve the list of urls of all the categories of a product with the following code:

```
<?php
    $categories = $_product->getCategoryIds();  //$_product: Mage_Catalog_Model_Product

    foreach ($categories AS $category) {
        echo Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category)->getUrl(); //get all the URLs here
    }
?>
```

**UPDATED:** (To exclude certain category)

```
<?php
    $categories = $_product->getCategoryIds();  //$_product: Mage_Catalog_Model_Product

    foreach ($categories AS $category) {
        if ($category != REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_HOME_CAT_ID_HERE) {
            $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category);
            echo "<a href=\"" . $cat->getUrl() . "\"><i class=\"test\"></i>See all " . $cat->getName() . "</a>";

            //to print only one link
            break;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Great, thanks!
But I want to skip the homepage category and also make it a href. We use this category for home (https://www.ourdomain/homepage/homepage-row-2) How can I achieve this?

Comment: @Jelle Sorry, but what do you mean by "We use this category for home"?

Comment: @Jelle And what if the product falls into more than 1 category (excluding the "homepage category")?

Comment: @Jelle Oh, do you mean the 6 products are in a "homepage category" which is created to display those 6 products only, and you want to exclude this particular category?

Comment: The products falls into just 2 categories. That is the category for the homepage. We call the category for the homepage (homepage-row-2). And the product falls into the category where their belong. So I want to display only the category where their belong and exclude the homepage category

Comment: @Jelle I have updated the answer.

Comment: Great!! :) Many thanks, works great! Is it also possible to display only the first category where this products falls into? In the case we use more than 1 category?

Comment: @Jelle I think you just have to put a `break;` in the if-block

Comment: Thanks, can you show how the code looks like than? Because I tried it, but it does not work. And is it possible to display some text inside the <a> Like (See all (category)</a>

Comment: @Jelle I have already included the `break;` statement above. Sure, you could just add any text as you like. And I would give an example above.

Comment: Last question, how can I add a line with an icon inside the a href? Like this <a href="/link"><i class="test"></i></a>

Comment: @Jelle Actually you could just add any HTML codes you want, just be sure to escape them correctly. Please check the updated code.